# Git repository is not showing in GitHub

Tags: django, git, github

I am new in using GitHub, I am trying to Upload a Django Project on `GitHub` from `Git Bash` BUT when i push it on GitHub then it is not showing in Browser.

**The Problem**

Git Repository is not uploading or showing in Browser.

**Folder Size**

```
35.4 MB
```

**What have i tried**

- git init

  ---*Output* :- Initialized empty Git repository in C:/doingstatic/myproject/.git/
- git add .

---*Output* :-

```
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in static/js/cropper.min.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

AND MANY MORE LINES.
```

- git commit -m "First Commit"

  ---*Output* :- ALL THE FILES THAT ARE IN FOLDER.
- git remote add origin *https://github.com/progam/rr.git*
- git push origin master

  ---*Output* :- Asking `Git` for Login and again after `SSH` asking for `Login`.

AND THEN :-

```
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
Enumerating objects: 541, done.
Counting objects: 100% (541/541), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (530/530), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (541/541), 54.35 MiB | 989.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 541 (delta 115), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

AND then i check it on `GitHub` nothing is appearing.

I don't know where is the problem.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Looks like you didn't log in?

Comment: It is asking for `login` and `password`. I login exactly as my login `username` and `password`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to increase the buffer size (it's due to the large repository size), so you have to increase it.

`git config http.postBuffer 524288000`

So by doing above(on git bash), git buffer size will get increase.

**EDIT:**   This may happen when you push first time without net connection or poor net connection. But when you try again using good connection 2,3 times problem will be solved.

Comment: My respository size is `35 MB`

Comment: The [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatdoescodehttppostBuffercodereallydo) states that this is not a general purpose solution and indicates breakage in your network somewhere.  Git handles streaming transfers just fine, and if your network is properly configured, it should, too.